# jquery "" error

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I have a question about embedding javascript/jQuery in C# strings. See the `hideQuestion` function in the `onclick` event in this code. I am adding this to C# as a string (please ignore line breaks added for clarity):

```
content += "$('#_question101')
   .append(\"
      <div class='ui-grid-c'>
         <div class='ui-block-a'>
            <a id='_bEdit1' href='#Question_01_01'
               onclick='aQ101(); hideQuestion('Question1', 'Question2');'
               data-role='button'>
               Aanpassen
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>\"
   );";
```

Because I have used `"` and `'` already, I can't use them in my function. Does anyone know how I can get this working? The function doesn't work because I have used both.

Comment: You need to switch the ' with " and " with '. except in $('#_question101')

Comment: The beginning of your append starts with an escape character. That probably won't work.

Comment: You can escape quotes with \ (backslash) in front of the quote i.e. "\'"

Comment: Argh. I hate edit wars, and I hate it when I have a good edit ready and can't do anything because an invalid pending edit needs approval...

Comment: That edit changes the entire question, in future please think before you post

Comment: @TomWalters The veritable edit war didn't help... kept driving it to the front page.

Comment: @ErikE I apologise for that, it appeared that someone was randomly changing the entire question

Comment: @TomWalters I hope my latest edit makes sense out of things. A record time for 9 edits for sure!

Comment: @ErikE I have to say it's made it much better, cheers!

Comment: @user1652050 using jquery to add elements with inline onclick handlers - is awful - if you're going to use jquery, _use_ jquery.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have any double quotes inside that which you are appending, so you don't need to worry, simply stop escaping them like so:

```
$('#_question101').append("<div class='ui-grid-c'><div class='ui-block-a'><a id='_bEdit1' href='#Question_01_01' onclick='aQ101(); \"hideQuestion('Question1', 'Question2'\")' data-role='button'>Aanpassen</a></div></div>");
```

Comment: That would break his code because there's a single quote following the onclick and another one inside the hideQuestion() function.

Comment: Tom please close the hideQuestion function

Comment: You are still missing the closing bracket on the hideQuestion function and the last braceright should also be removed.

Comment: Using the code in your question, have your tried simply `\'` inside the `hideQuestion()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Use like this

```
$('#_question101').append("<div class='ui-grid-c'><div class='ui-block-a'><a id='_bEdit1' href='#Question_01_01' onclick='aQ101();hideQuestion(\"Question1\", \"Question2\");'  data-role='button'>Aanpassen</a></div></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
$('#_question101').append("<div class='ui-grid-c'><div class='ui-block-a'><a id='_bEdit1' href='#Question_01_01' onclick='aQ101(); hideQuestion(\'Question1\', \'Question2\')' data-role='button'>Aanpassen</a></div></div>");
```

Comment: you can use same quotes inside quotes, as long as your quotes which are inside, are escaped. So there is no syntax error in that string

Answer (score 1):

Some Notes:

1. JavaScript actually supports three different quote marks: `'`, `"`, and `` ` ``. You can use these to good effect when you must have multiple levels of escaping.
2. JavaScript allows you to escape quote marks with `\`. Since your JavaScript is in fact a C# string which *also* escapes quote marks with `\`, then you have to escape the backslash itself, so that C# will emit an actual backslash, to be treated in JavaScript as an escape character.
3. With all this escaping and quote-switching going on, it can be very difficult to isolate where a problem is. For all you know, after trying some quote-selection and quote-escaping tweaks here and there, you're emitting valid HTML but have a bug in your program!

In light of these I recommend you do a few things:

1. Each time you try something new, *take a look directly at the raw, source HTML in the web page*. Don't even bother clicking your button until you've validated it. Go ahead and trying using `` ` `` as one of your quoting levels, but check the results before you post back here again.
2. Step back and really rethink how you're doing this. Do you realize how difficult it is going to be to maintain JavaScript embedded inside HTML embedded inside JavaScript embedded inside a C# string? Seriously. Try to separate all the different concerns through use of different containers, or a class, or files.

   - You could build your JavaScript or HTML fragments *first* in a separate variable, then, escape that string as you bundle it into the next outer layer, doing this repeatedly until you finally get to the C# string.
   - You could store the HTML or JavaScript in a resource file, which you read from in your C# code, fully taking care of the escaping problem.
3. Try to separate your event JavaScript from your dynamic JavaScript. Instead of putting the Javascript code inline `onclick="oneMoreLevelOfEscapedJavascriptHere()"` why not use `.on('click', fnname()`? This is the industry-accepted, best-practice way of wiring up javascript events.
4. Last, why not use an environment/ language designed for web scripting that allows literal blocks of unescaped HTML to be present? Then you can avoid a whole level of indirection. If you're already using ASP.Net with C#, then there is a way to not have to stick the HTML into a string first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use character escaping there with `\`

```
onclick='aQ101(); hideQuestion(\"Question1\", \"Question2\");'
```

for the update:

`content += "$('#_question101').append('<div class=\"ui-grid-c\"><div class=\"ui-block-a\"><a id=\"_bEdit1\" href=\"#Question_01_01\" onclick=\"aQ101(); **hideQuestion(\\'Question1\\', \\'Question2\\');**\" data-role=\"button\">Aanpassen</a></div></div>');";`

level 1 : `"`
level 2 : `'`
level 3 : `\"`
level 4 : `\\'`

Comment: Doesn't your Level 4 have to be `\\'` so that the backslash will be persisted into the javascript?

Comment: Yes, as I think of it, you're right, it'll print as `'` again. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: does it give you a syntax error, or something else related to your javascript?

Comment: I can't see a button. I can't see if it doesn't work. I just answered your question. Don't expect much.